# Can we clone Salesforce standard objects?

Tags: administration, standard-objects

I want to give a custom object equal org-wide default to accounts. It is possible we clone Salesforce standard objects.

Answer (score 1):

Setting up org-wide defaults is a very straight-forward effort, just a picklist change.  I'm not sure I understand why you'd need to clone an object to replicate the settings.
Try here and see just how easy it is:
https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=admin_sharing.htm&language=en_US